# How to implement a connection pool?

Tags: mysql, c

I'm using civetweb as a (websocket) server. I have some handlers for when I receive data, that will query mysql. These will spawn as a thread, every time there is a request.

Until now I was only using one mysql connection with the database, which I setup on the start off the program, in combination with the mongoose library. But with the threaded requests, it's causing me headaches, since mysql isn't thread-safe from the time you do mysql_select() until mysql_store_result(). I have tried putting a mutex around these mysql functions, but then perfomce drops a tenfold (from ~750 requests/second to ~75 requests/second).

What is the correct way to handle this? I've heard about a 'connection pool', but it's hard to find some simple examples with google (or wrap my head around a sane implementation).

It seems unlikely I'm the first person to encounter such a problem :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you.  I'd put it in a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet.

I had the same problem in VB.NET when I added multi threading to my application.  To correct it there I made sure to call connection.open before all of my queries and added "pooling=true;" to the end of my mysql Connection String.  Mysql will determine if it needs to open a connection or using existing one.